# Will this break my phone?

Tags: rom-flashing, fastboot

I have a Verizon HTC One M7. Since it's Verizon, the bootloader obviously locked. If I were to use `fastboot boot twrp-m7wlv.img` and then try to flash a custom ROM, would that damage my phone?

Comment: You can't boot an external image with a locked bootloader, and if you somehow could and flashed an unsigned image boot would fail and you would have a brick. Actually, on stock on M7 I don't think you can boot twrp directly even with an unlocked bootloader.

Comment: "He who asks is a fool for 5 minutes, but he who doesn't is a fool forever" (I think that's how that one goes) Ace is right though - You won't be able to do much with a locked bootloader. Can't you unlock it? (I'm sure you can make it unlockable in the developer settings)

Comment: @DanBrown Can't unlock it, it's Verizon branded. They made it incompatible with htcdev

Comment: Oh. Right. (UK guy w/ 3, so didn't know) That's a dick move.